# яндекс касса и jquery

Tags: jquery, яндекс-касса

Всем привет, никак не могу разобраться, как написать post-запрос к яндекс кассе. Сам запрос, который ниже проверял, все работает

```js
var headers = {
 'Idempotence-Key': '0ccb7813-e63d-4377-93c5-476cb93038f31',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
};

$.ajax({
    url: "https://payment.yandex.net/api/v3/payments",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) { 
      xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("637483:test_kycM5d75aQBO11HZ2pdryghI4L2mu68X4piqbSIcm4U"));
    },
  headers: headers,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    data: {
        "amount": {
          "value": "100.00",
          "currency": "RUB"
        },
        "capture": true,
        "confirmation": {
          "type": "redirect",
          "return_url": "https://www.merchant-website.com/return_url"
        },
        "description": "Заказ №1"
  },
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(){
      console.log("Cannot get data");
    }
});
```

Оригинал запроса на curl:

```js
curl https://payment.yandex.net/api/v3/payments \
  -X POST \
  -u 637483:test_kycM5d75aQBO11HZ2pdryghI4L2mu68X4piqbSIcm4U \
  -H 'Idempotence-Key: 0ccb7813-e63d-4377-93c5-476cb93038f31' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
        "amount": {
          "value": "100.00",
          "currency": "RUB"
        },
        "capture": true,
        "confirmation": {
          "type": "redirect",
          "return_url": "https://www.merchant-website.com/return_url"
        },
        "description": "Заказ №1"
      }'
```

Буду рад любой помощи (:

Comment: А что получаете при попытке выполнения кода на js?

Comment: выводит сообщение из error — Cannot get data

Comment: А что во вкладке network происходит с запросом?

Comment: Preflight response is not successful

Comment: Нажимаете на строчку с целевым запросом, там открываете вкладку Headers и смотрите, всё ли корректно уходит: данные, заголовки и т.п.

Comment: проблема в авторизации, как я понимаю, вот в этой строчке: xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("637483:test_kycM5d75aQBO11HZ2pdryghI4L2mu68X4piqbSIcm4U")); https://www.dropbox.com/s/b0jl2d765ivnwk9/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202019-09-14%2020.15.38.png?dl=0

Comment: На самом деле, скриншот достаточно неинформативный. Можно поступить проще - есть такая программа Postman, которая позволяет совершать http запросы. Можете прямо в ней сделать запрос с требуемыми параметрами и потом, нажав кнопку code получить код запроса на jquery.

Comment: https://codepen.io/drewsher/pen/qBWyZMR?editors=0011 смотрите, вот код из постмана, но в консоль ничего не возвращается. в самом постмане ответ получаю

Comment: Нужно смотреть результаты запроса в браузере, как и писал ранее. Что уходит, что возвращается. И, кстати, в этом коде уже должна выводиться в консоль сама ошибка, что произошло. Что там написано?

Comment: ошибка не выводится, тот код, который отдал постман странно работает, точнее не работает

Comment: А если вот это "Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("637483:test_kycM5d75aQBO11HZ2pdryghI4L2mu68X4piqbSIcm4U" в header добавить? А beforeSend удалить.
И там точно будет Basic а не Bearer? Можете попробовать и так, и так. В ваш первоначальный код.

Comment: попробовал по всякому, результат отрицательный. очень странно. Сейчас на php пишу и все нормально. очень странно